# How to add a field calculated from another model table in Agile Toolkit?

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

atk4.2.1

I have two models Invoice and Payment, I want to add a field (expression) in the invoice,  I can calculate the already amount paid (it can have several partial payment), I added a join and an expression, dut they don't work, what is the right way to write that expression?

```
class Model_Invoice extends Model_Table {
    public $table='invoice';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Customer');
        $this->hasOne('Plan');
        $this->addField('date')->type('date');
        $this->addField('amount')->type('money');
        $this->addField('cancelled')->type('boolean')->defaultValue(false);

        $this->join('payment','id');
        $this->addExpression('amountPaid')->set('sum(payment.amount)')
       //*****above expression is not working*********//
    }
}
```

.

```
class Model_Payment extends Model_Table {
    public $table='payment';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->hasOne('Invoice');
        $this->addField('date')->type('date');
        $this->addField('concept');
        $this->addField('amount')->type('money');
    }
}
```

I might an expression like this instead:

```
$this->addExpression('amountPaid')->set('(SELECT sum(amount) FROM payment where invoice_id=**CURRENT ID**)');
```

But how do I get the **CURRENT ID** in the Model???

Comment: I was able to get the CURRENT ID in the model with this (I got it somewhere in the devel group): $this->_dsql()->getField('id')

Answer (score 2):

Got it!
It was somehow documented here: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/model/intro

This is the right way to do it:
Inside Model_Invoice:

```
    $this->hasMany('Payment');
    $this->addExpression('amountPaid')->set($this->refSQL('Payment')->sum('amount'));
```

Now I really understood what's the porpuse of hasMany()