# Agile toolkit - access calculated fields (expressions) from dsql?

Tags: sql, atk4

I have a model with a calculated field:

```
class Model_UsedItem extends Model_Table {
public $table='usedItems';

function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->hasOne('Case', 'case_id', 'id');
    $this->hasOne('Item', 'item_id', 'description');
    $i = $this->join('Items', 'item_id');
    $i->addField('unitCost')->hidden(true);
    $this->addField('quantity')
    $this->addExpression('subTotal')->set('unitCost * quantity')->type('money');
}
```

(Table `usedItems` contains id, case_id, item_id, and quantity.The value for `unitCost` is stored in a separate table `Items` which also contains `description`. It is modelled as `Model_Item` but I did not include it here)

And here is my `Model_Case`:

```
class Model_Case extends Model_MyTable {
public $table='cases';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->getElement('id')->system(false);
    $this->addField('date')->type('date');
    $this->hasMany('UsedItem', 'case_id');
}
```

This works perfectly fine and I can use CRUD with an expander to see each Case and list of associated UsedItem entries, along with calculated field subTotal.

But I also want Model_Case to have a field Total that is calculated from `SUM(subTotal)`. I made it work by doing

```
$this->addExpression('Total')->set(function($model,$select){
    return $select->dsql()
        ->table('usedItems')->join('items','item_id')
        ->field($select->expr('SUM(quantity*unitCost)'))
        ->where('case_id',$select->getField('id'));
})->type('money');
```

This seems inefficient to do it like this when I have already written code for subTotal. Plus this is the simplest case where this concept would be used in my application and more complicated cases will end up completely illegible (and less efficient? I'm not exactly sure how it works).

How can I get `Model_Case` to access `Model_UsedItem` and perform another calculation on it? DSQL only acts on the tables, not the models, so that won't work here, right?

I am used to being able to do this in MS Access where queries can call each other as if they were tables, so `Query1` could calculate `SELECT SUM(quantity*unitCost) AS subTotal` and then `Query2` could do `SELECT SUM(subTotal) FROM Query1`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At first glance it looks that there is no better way to do this, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I think it is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11596300/204819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11596300/204819. what's important is that the code produces ONE query. As a parameter to sum() you can specify a field which is also an expression, it should work fine.

Comment: thanks romanish, that works. I saw that but did not realize it would apply. Is there a list of methods I can call on refSQL() ? SUM and COUNT seem to work but AVERAGE or AVG don't. I tried to construct an average function by simply passing `set($this->refSQL('UsedItem')->sum('subTotal')/$this->refSQL('UsedItem')->count())` but it just returns 1 every time - it seems I can retrieve the value but not perform any math on it.

Comment: refSQL returns Model object, so you should be able to use any Model class methods there. Also you can call DSQL object refSQL()->_dsql and use its expr() method and so on.

Comment: Thanks DarkSide. I figured it out, based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596506/how-to-do-math-operations-with-model-fields-or-expressions-in-agile-toolkit

I'm still trying to figure out what I can do with refSQL. I know it returns a model but I'm not sure how to perform operations on all of its records.

Comment: refSQL is basically meant for using in sub-queries

Comment: Two differences between ref() and refSQL is that that refSQL does not require model to be link condition using field expression rather then actual loaded value of your model.  ref: case_id=123, refSQL: case_id=case.id.