# refSQL() cannot handle conditions based on expressions? (database query error "no such column")

Tags: atk4

This is a follow up from this question: [Agile toolkit - access calculated fields (expressions) from dsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640399/agile-toolkit-access-calculated-fields-expressions-from-dsql/) . I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm just missing something.

Here's my current code:

```
class Model_UsedItem extends Model_Table {
public $table='usedItems';

function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->hasOne('Case', 'case_id', 'id');
    $this->hasOne('Item', 'item_id', 'description');
    $i = $this->join('Items', 'item_id');
    $i->addField('unitCost')->hidden(true);
    $this->addField('quantity')
    $this->addExpression('subTotal')->set('quantity * unitCost')->type('money');
}

class Model_Case extends Model_Table {
public $table='cases';

function init(){
    parent::init();
    $this->getElement('id')->system(false);
    $this->addField('date')->type('date');
    $this->hasMany('UsedItem', 'case_id');
    $this->addExpression('Total')->set($this->refSQL('UsedItem')->sum('subTotal'))->type('money');
}
```

This works fine. Now say I want to modify `Model_UsedItem` so that it only selects rows where `subTotal < 10` - simple: `$this->addCondition('subTotal','<',10);`. Now if I load `Model_UsedItem` into a grid, I see just rows with the condition.

When I go to load `Model_Case` into a grid, I expected to see the `Total` column consist of `sum(subTotal) where subTotal < '10'`.

Instead it throws a Database Query Failed error: "no such column subTotal". debug() shows that it tried to do this:

```
select `id`,`date`,(select sum(quantity * unitCost) from `usedItems` inner join `Items` as `_I` on `_I`.`id` = `usedItems`.`item_id` where `subTotal` < "10" and `usedItems`.`case_id` = `cases`.`id` ) `Total`
```

I'm able to add conditions based on real fields, so I'm pretty sure this just needs to be

```
select `id`,`date`,(select sum(`subTotal`) from (select (quantity * unitCost) `subTotal` from `usedItems` inner join `Items` as `_I` on `_I`.`id` = `usedItems`.`item_id` where `usedItems`.`case_id` = `cases`.`id` and `subTotal` < 10)) `Total`
```

but how do I convince agile toolkit to do that?

EDIT: @DarkSide was correct, my code does read ('quantity * unitCost'), I revised above.

Comment: are you sure you posted your code correctly? In model you have unitCost * quantity, but in SQL it shows quantity * unitCost. Something is not right here. In theory it's possible that ATK have not implemented such behaviour that condition from related model is inherited, but I doubt. Please revise your code and I'll take a look at this later. To which model you add debug()?

Comment: Actually strange thing is that sum(subTotal) is not in resulting SQL. Try to debug SQLs even without addCondition. Are they OK then?

Comment: without addCondition it is fine as I believe refSQL() copies over the contents of the expression, it just does not include the name assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that it's some kind of bug (or not implemented feature) in ATK.

You got SQL:

```
select `id`,`date`,(select sum(quantity * unitCost) from `usedItems` inner join `Items` as `_I` on `_I`.`id` = `usedItems`.`item_id` where `subTotal` < "10" and `usedItems`.`case_id` = `cases`.`id` ) `Total`
```

but in this case it should be `(quantity * unitCost)` instead of `subTotal` in WHERE part like this:

```
select `id`,`date`,(select sum(quantity * unitCost) from `usedItems` inner join `Items` as `_I` on `_I`.`id` = `usedItems`.`item_id` where (quantity * unitCost) < "10" and `usedItems`.`case_id` = `cases`.`id` ) `Total`
```

I wonder how debug() of `Model_UsedItems` looks like when you have condition set. Can you tell me? Do it have `(quantity * unitCost)<10` or `subTotal<10`?

---

**EDIT:**

I just created your testcase and tried it with about 3 months old ATK 4.2.5 version and also current one from github. Everything looks OK.

**Complete test case** (name it `a.php` and put it in `/page` folder):

```
class Model_UsedItem extends Model_Table {
    public $table='usedItems';
    function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->hasOne('Case', 'case_id', 'id');
        $i = $this->join('Items', 'item_id');
        $i->addField('unitCost');
        $this->addField('quantity');
        $this->addExpression('subTotal')->set('quantity * unitCost');
        $this->addCondition('subTotal','<',10);
    }
}
class Model_Case extends Model_Table {
    public $table='cases';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('date');
        $this->hasMany('UsedItem', 'case_id');
        $this->addExpression('Total')->set($this->refSQL('UsedItem')->sum('subTotal'));
    }
}
class page_a extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $m = $this->add('Model_Case')->debug();
        $this->add('Grid')->setModel($m);
    }
}
```

**Produced SQL:**

```
select `date`,(select sum(quantity * unitCost) `subTotal` from `usedItems` inner join `Items` as `_I` on `_I`.`id` = `usedItems`.`item_id` where quantity * unitCost < 10 and `usedItems`.`case_id` = `cases`.`id` ) `Total`,`id` from `cases`
```

As you can see it has `subTotal` alias and doesn't use alias (use full expression) in `where` part because aliases in SQL SELECT should be used only in `having` or `order by` (after select executes and gets resultset) not in `where`.

Comment: `Model_UsedItem` selects `(quantity * unitCost) subTotal` then WHERE statement performs `where subTotal < 10`. when the model is referenced by another model, the WHERE statement is preserved as is, but the SELECT statement renders without assigning the column name.

I've managed to get what I want working by doing `addExpression()->set(*pure SQL here*)` for now.

Comment: Yeah, then it looks like a bug. There should always be alias rendered after any type of expression. Can you report that in https://github.com/atk4/atk4/issues too, just in case?

Comment: I'll take a look at this bug and maybe will be able to fix this at some point. BUT do you use +/- latest 4.2.5 version from github? if no, then please try this out with latest 4.2.5 version.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me - see my complete test case in edited post above. Please test this with current ATK version 4.2.5 from github. Maybe such bug was in older versions and is fixed already.

Comment: tested and working in 4.2.5. My apologies as I downloaded from agiletoolkit.org recently but somehow got 4.2.4 (in which this bug does exist). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Keep your eye on new ATK 4.3 version. It'll have a lot of changes and improvements. You can test it already from Github 4.3 branch.